# Define Document Type in plain XML for Nuxeo

Tags: nuxeo

I try to grasp the mechanics of Nuxeo and as such started with all tutorials and documents around. I put together a bundle that seemed quite right for me and tried now for several hours to make it work in any flavor - without success.

Using Nuxeo 8.3.

Anything i am missing?

The manifest at META_INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.foo.nuxeo.tutorial.tutorial-demo1;singlet
 on=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Name: tutorial-demo1
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Vendor: de.foo.nuxeo.tutorial
Nuxeo-Component: OSGI-INF/foo-demo-component-core-types.xml,OSGI-INF/foo-demo-component-ui-types.xml
```

A core document type at OSG-INF/foo-demo-component-core-types.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component name="de.foo.demo.component.core.types" version="1.0">

    <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.core.schema.TypeService" point="schema">
        <schema name="foo" src="schemas/foo-demo-foo.xsd"
            prefix="isfoo" />
    </extension>

    <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.core.schema.TypeService" point="doctype" >
        <doctype extends="File" name="FooFile">n
            <schema name="foo" />
        </doctype>
    </extension>

</component>
```

A ECM document type at OSGI-INF/foo-demo-component-ui-types.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component name="de.foo.demo.component.ui.types" version="1.0">

    <require>org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.types</require>

    <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.types.TypeService"
        point="types">

        <type id="FooFile">
            <label>Foo File</label>
            <icon>/icons/file.gif</icon>
            <bigIcon>/icons/file_100.png</bigIcon>
            <category>SimpleDocument</category>
            <description>A foo file</description>
            <default-view>view_documents</default-view>
            <layouts mode="any">
                <layout>heading</layout>
                <layout>file</layout>
            </layouts>
        </type>

        <type id="Folder">
            <subtypes> 
                <type>FooFile</type>
            </subtypes>
        </type>


    </extension>

</component>
```

A schema at schemas/foo-demo-foo.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://www.foo.de/nuxeo/schemas/foo/"
    xmlns="http://www.foo.de/nuxeo/schemas/foo/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="gnu" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="gnat" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Packed in a jar and deployed to nxserver/bundles. After a  restart i see the bundle loaded in the administrator view, no errors in the log file. When i create a new document, i do not see the new type...

What am i missing?

Comment: There's a typo: `name="FooFile">n`

Comment: Did you apply/follow some specific tutorial or documentation?

Comment: @Julien Carsique, you are reading carefully... this must be a typ from copy&paste, sorry

Comment: @Julien Carsique, as most tutorials are concerned with Nuxeo studio, this is kind of "homebrew". In the meantime i have  a more elaborated version and i can create files. I assume that i simply did not dig deep enough (as this declaration does not support files in workspaces but folders only).

Comment: The current, extended version can be found here https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/4611a80ded0e466480035b8ff0035a49/NothingToPreviewException-when-adding-a-document-without-an-initial-upload . While one can create Files with this stub, there is a reproducible error condition when creating a file without upload.